# JQuery Animation stutters on first execution

Tags: jquery, slider

I am using this plugin http://matthewlein.com/experiments/slots.html for an animation I want to achieve, but when you first execute the animation it stutters a bit, especially in chrome. Is there a way to avoid this?

http://machinas.com/wip/jackwolfskin/hiking/

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Advanced transformations, translations and animations may be improved by offloading them to the GPU for better rendering performance in the browser. Most browsers support hardware-acceleration.

Maybe this article leads you to a solution:
[Increasing site performance with hardware accelerated css](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/increase-your-sites-performance-with-hardware-accelerated-css)